# Design of the 'new tags' section in moderator tools is ugly

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, 10k-tools

Recently I got moderator tools privilege (10k) on ruSO and felt that the design of the page was quite ugly.

One of the worst culprits was the table in the "New tags" section- it's not aligned horizontally:

> [image: new tags]

And another example, on Hinduism.SE:

> [image: new tags]

The alignment and varying column-size makes for a very ugly-looking, cluttered sight.

Is it possible to make y-pos for each line the same? (Maybe this could be fixed by forbidding to move `x count` to the new line.)

Comment: adding `.tag-col {
    white-space: nowrap;
}` does resolve this issue. I didn't check if this has consequences anywhere else but on this page it didn't lead to new issues.

Comment: Moderator tools have a lot of design and usability issues in general (see https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3062)

Comment: @Cai I know that there are extremely more issues than one (upvoted you post), but this is not a reason no to fix it. I propose to fix it step by step.

Comment: @alexolut oh yes of course, it should be fixed I agree!